# NFS client permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs

I am trying to configure the permissions of an NFS client and would like to allow on client nfs to be able to copy the files and not delete the files. how can i do this?

Is it possible to restrict reading, writing and execution, giving permission to certain groups in the nfs client?

When configuring /etc/exports not possible?

I still don't understand properly how nfs handles client permissions

best